# Multiple pages on one page

Tags: html, navbar

I am creating a personal site. I will have a fixed navbar with links to multiple pages I've created for each list item. How do I also show all those pages on one page, while having them open using the links in the navbar?

Comment: You're looking to create a "Single Page Application" utilizing a router system. Try starting with [search engine of your choice] and come back to SO with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

link:-https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Creating_multiple_pages_with_navigation_menus